# Android Intent not Carrying a Bundle of Strings

Tags: android, android-intent, android-button

In below code, intent from the first activity to the second only carries 1 string and I need it to carry 2. I have tried to use bundle to achieve this but I think my problem is in this line

```
extras.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
```

The second problem that you might notice is I need to get the text to be colored by using a string entered on the first page, however I need to spend more time researching this and the first problem is more important.

If someone could help me to solve this first problem it would be most appreciated

I have all the relevant code below.

Main Activity

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE_COLOR = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE2";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }    


/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage (View view)   {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    EditText editTextcolor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message_color);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    String messagecolor = editTextcolor.getText().toString();
    i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_COLOR, messagecolor);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(i);
    // Do something in response to button

}

}
```

Second Activity

```
 package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the message from the intent

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String messagecolor = bundle.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE_COLOR);
        String message = bundle.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);


        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
        textView.setTextSize(100);
        textView.setText(message);
        textView.setText(messagecolor);


        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);

        // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar API
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)   {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

XML File

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/edit_message_color"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message_color" />

    <Button         
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:text="@string/button_send"
            android:textColor="@color/royal_blue"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:background="@color/pale_green"
            android:onClick="sendMessage"  />     

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where you call your sendMessage() method in your first activity named as MainActiivity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put that `extras` Bundle in intent extra and then in next activity you will get the correct response

```
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    extras.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE_COLOR, messagecolor );
    i.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
     public void sendMessage (View view)   {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
            EditText editTextcolor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message_color);
            String message = editText.getText().toString();
            String messagecolor = editTextcolor.getText().toString();

            i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_COLOR, messagecolor);
i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
            startActivity(i);
            // Do something in response to button

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Edit your sendMessage method to

```
public void sendMessage (View view)   
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    EditText editTextcolor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message_color);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    String messagecolor = editTextcolor.getText().toString();
    i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_COLOR, messagecolor);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add id attribute in button in layout file and implement onClick method on this button in your main activity.

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE_COLOR = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE2";
    Button b;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b = (Button)findVIewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
               public void onClick(View v)
                 {
                     sendMessage();
                  }
         )};
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }    


/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage (View view)   {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    EditText editTextcolor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message_color);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    String messagecolor = editTextcolor.getText().toString();
    i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_COLOR, messagecolor);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(i);
    // Do something in response to button

}

}
```

And your layout code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/edit_message_color"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message_color" />

    <Button         
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
            android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:text="@string/button_send"
            android:textColor="@color/royal_blue"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:background="@color/pale_green" />


 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("key") to get array.